# Does blackberry OS framework do http connection reuse?

Tags: blackberry

Does blackberry framework use connection reuse for http connection? I use `connectionFactory.getConnection("api.abc.com")` . I have noticed that the first call (simple rest call for ex, getting number of unread messages) from my app takes about 4 seconds but all the subsequent calls take less than a second to complete. I have noticed that the same call when made after another call takes less than a second, so I am thinking that blackberry uses http connection reuse. Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Link to [your question on blackberry forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Does-blackberry-OS-framework-do-http-connection-reuse/m-p/2000165).  I will also say that many smartphone OS's will smartly turn off (or turn down) the radio when it thinks the network is idle.  So, you may also see better performance after the first run, because the radio was in a low-power state when you attempted the first connection.  That's just a guess, though.

Comment: We tested the performance,and we noticed that SSL handshake was consuming the most time. but for subsequent calls,app bypassed the SSL handshake, hence it was quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this on the server, by looking at the network activity that actually makes it to the server.  My own testing indicates BlackBerry devices do not re-use connections.